# Store database in sql server client wise

Tags: database, database-design, sql-server-2008-r2, relational-database

I have develop application in which i have created different logins for every client.Our applications is having so many clients like job portals or facebook and every client having huge amount of data .If i use single database then one table get huge amount of data for all client

I find out one solution for that and solution is to create separate database for every client but as there are so many client then we need to create so many databases so that not correct solution

Please can you tell me right way to implement this by using sql server 2008 r2

Thanks

Comment: "one table get huge amount of data for all client"  Why do you think this is a problem that needs solving ?

Comment: @ErwinSmout yes your right but problem is that single table get lakhs of record so we find performance slow down problem

Answer (score 0):

You could try having one schema per client, and that client's logon has that schema as their default and is the only schema that they have access to. However you'll have a lot of schemas so it may not be much help! (Also, iof you're using something like EF to access the db it won't work.)

Single database good:

- Easy management

Single database bad:

- Possible performance problems (although not until you get into
  billions of rows; one DB I designed had a table with more than 21B
  rows after 3 months; lucky I made the IDENTITY column a BigInt!)
- Security issues/complexity: how do you stop one client accessing
  another's data?
- Single point of failure for all clients

Multiple database good

- Security is easier
- Single point of failure per client (assuming multiple DB Servers to
  spread that load also)
- More flexibility in applying updates: some clients are OK with
  Wednesday, some with Thursday

I'm sure that there are other issues as well. Really it's up to your requirements and how they can best be met,

Multiple db bad:

- More management required
- Given a DB has overhead, your overhead resource usage goes up